# Count of sub-select in influxdb not returning anything

Tags: influxdb

I've got some data structured as such

`select * from rules where time > now() - 1m limit 5`

```
name: rules
time                ackrate consumers deliverrate hostname    publishrate ready redeliverrate shard unacked version
----                ------- --------- ----------- --------    ----------- ----- ------------- ----- ------- -------
1513012628943000000 864     350       861.6       se-rabbit14 975.8       0     0             14    66      5
1513012628943000000 864.8   350       863         se-rabbit9  920.8       0     0             09    64      5
1513012628943000000 859.8   350       860.2       se-rabbit8  964.2       0     0             08    58      5
1513012628943000000 864.8   350       863.6       se-rabbit16 965.4       0     0             16    64      5
1513012631388000000 859.8   350       860.2       se-rabbit8  964.2       0     0             08    58      5
```

I want to calculate the percentage of 'up-time' defined as the amount of time when the queue has no ready messages.

I can get the maximum number of ready in each minute

`select max(ready) from rules where time > now() - 1h group by time(1m) limit 5`

```
name: rules
time                max
----                ---
1513009560000000000 0
1513009620000000000 0
1513009680000000000 0
1513009740000000000 0
1513009800000000000 0
```

Using a sub-query, I can select only the minutes that have values ready.

`select ready from (select max(ready) as ready from rules where time > now() - 1h group by time(1m)) where ready > 0`

```
name: rules
time                ready
----                -----
1513010520000000000 49
1513013280000000000 57
```

I wanted to get a count of these values and then doing a bit of math calculate a percentage. In this case, with 2 results in the last hour,

((60 minutes * 1 hour) - 2) / (60 minutes * 1 hour)) == 96%

When I try to count this though, I get no response.

`select count(ready) from (select max(ready) as ready from rules where time > now() - 1h group by time(1m)) where ready > 0`

This is v1.2.2.

How can I return a count of the number of results?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to upgrade from v1.2.2 to v1.3.8. Using the later version.

```
select count(ready) from (select max(ready) as ready from rules where time > now() - 1h group by time(1m)) where ready > 0
name: rules
time count
---- -----
0    6
```